# $this variable in Zend Layout

Tags: php, zend-framework

I was going through some tutorial and documentation about zend framework, most of things made sense until i came across `$this` variable in `/application/layout/scripts/layout.phtml`, it was mentioned that `$this` is an instance of the view object that was created during bootstrapping.

to my knowledge you cannot use `$this` as the variable name as because `$this` is a reserved keyword for php used to refer the same object within the class context. any attempt to use it as a variable will result in Fatal error with the following error message `Fatal error: Cannot re-assign $this` and as per the author's statement `There is a variable, $this, available which is an instance of the view object`, i am unable to understand the theory behind this. how come `$this` is being used out of the class context?

Comment: your answer is in this zend forum. The same question has been asked here and it has been answered http://forums.zend.com/viewtopic.php?f=69&t=16873

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's actually being used in the context of an object.  You should look at the code yourself, but the basic idea behind render() (which is the toString method by proxy):

```
public function render()
{
    //Start output buffering
    ob_start();
    include $this->viewScript;
    //Get the content from the include
    $content = ob_get_flush();
    return $content;
}
```

Zend Framework does it a bit more complexly so that it's a bit more flexible than that, but it's the basic idea.

Then, inside of the viewScript, it's technically inside of the render() method just as if the code were literally in that "include ..." place. (Oversimplifying that, but the general idea holds.)

Comment: great answer. never thought php could do this :).

Comment: Thanks rjz.  Your answer is basically the same, just a tiny bit off from how Zend does it :).  And yeah, Ibrahim, include can do some rather weird things.  It is almost exactly like the C/C++ #include in that it basically smacks the content of the file right where the include is. A rather interesting use of it is function blah() { include 'somefile.php'; } where somefile.php contains something like *return array(...);* It is then a function that returns the array defined in a file.  (Can be used in a few situations to be useful, though this was a bad example..)

Answer (score 3):

It's probably being used *in* the class context. Imagine the view being created along the following lines:

```
class View {

  public function render($viewfile = 'views/myviewfile.phtml') {
    ob_start();
      include($viewfile);
      $view_data = ob_get_contents();
    ob_end_clean();

    echo $view_data;
  }
}
```

The view presentation process is probably more complex than simply capturing an `include`d view file, but you can see how `$this` would be available to the view when `View::render()` is called.